# racket programming: how to add a new line after 2 white space character?

Tags: string, scheme, racket

I am currently using Dr Racket to do the programming and the task that I am required to do is to give a prompt to a user for an input file. Using the integer values in the input file, the program will execute two functions (two-lhs and two-rhs) that calculates sum of N squares, and output the result to a prompted output file; having the value from two-lhs to be listed on the left side and the value from two-rhs on the right side.

For example: suppose there is a file named 'data' in the directory where line one has the integer 25 and line two has 7, and line three has 9. User that inputs 'data' as an input file and 'testing' as an output file, the output file named 'testing' will be created in the directory with following values and format:

```
(results from two-lhs)     (results from two-rhs)
5525 5525
140 140
285 285
```

This is my current code with comments of my understanding:

```
#lang racket

(define squared ;helper function for two lhs
  (lambda (x) (* x x)))



(define Two-LHS 
  (lambda (n)
    (cond((= n 0) 0)
         (else 
          (+ (squared n) (Two-LHS(- n 1)))))))



(define Two-RHS 
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((= n 0) 0)
          (else
           (/ (* n (+ n 1) (+ (* n 2) 1)) 6)))))


(define in ;function that reads in the input file from user
  (lambda ()
    (let((pin(open-input-file (symbol->string (read))))) ;prompts the user for input file. pin = the input-port
      (let f ((x(read pin))) ;f is a procedure that reads the input port?
        (if(eof-object? x) ; x reads the value inside pin and if x happens to be end of file object
           (begin          ; then closes the input-port
             (close-input-port pin)
             '())
           (cons (Two-LHS x)(cons (Two-RHS x)(f(read pin))))) ;else using the x, executes two lhs and rhs until x reaches
        ))))                                                  ; end of file to close the port

(define write-lst 
  (lambda (lst outp) ;lst = input file, outp = output file
    (if(eq? lst '()) ; if input file contains an empty list
       (close-output-port outp) ; the output-port will be closed
       (begin                   ; else execute begin
         (write (car lst) outp) ; which writes the first element of the list to the output file
         (display #\space outp) ; will add whitespace after each element to the output file.
         (newline outp) ; was thinking this would add newline on the output file after each iteration, but need a way to add newline after every 2 whitespace. 
         (write-lst (cdr lst) outp))))) ;recurses back to write-lst function with the next element in the list without
                                        ;the first element until it becomes an empty list so that output-port could close.

(define out ;will be renamed to two-sum, since this is the function that will write to the output file.
  (lambda (lst) ;lst = input file
    (let((pout(open-output-file (symbol->string (read))))) ; prompts the user for the output file, pout = the output-port
      (write-lst lst pout); uses write-list function to write out to output file
      )))
(out (in))
```

The output file I get running my code is:

```
5525 
5525 
140 
140 
285 
285
```

How can I make the output file to be formatted correctly?
Any help in the right direction would be extremely appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can levarage Racket's [`fprintf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._fprintf%29%29) procedure to make things easier, and iterate over the list two elements at a time - assuming that it has an even number of elements:

```
(define write-lst
  (lambda (lst outp)
    (if (null? lst)
        (close-output-port outp)
        (begin
          (fprintf outp "~a ~a~n" (car lst) (cadr lst))
          (write-lst (cddr lst) outp)))))
```

The trick is here, in the format string: `"~a ~a~n"`. It states: print an object, a whitespace, another object and a new line. And we pass the current element `(car lst)` and the second element `(cadr lst)` - in fact, we could just use the `first` and `second` procedures, which are easier to understand. Finally, in the recursion we advance two elements: `(cddr lst)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and editing my post for clearer view.